# angular how to render html markup inside component's template

Tags: angular, html, templates, markup

How do i display html markup inside angular component's template.

if template.component.html is the template file, how do i lay out html markup like this:

```
<form action="" novalidate>
  <label for="">
    <span>Full Name:</span>
    <input type="text" name="fullName" placeholder="your name">
  </label>
  <div>
    <label for="">
      <span>Email:</span>
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="your email address">
    </label>
    <label for="">
      <span>Confirm Email:</span>
      <input type="email" name="confirmEmail" placeholder="confirm email address">
    </label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

such that the browser renders the markup as is and not the controls?

One option that worked for me is when i just replaced the < and > with "&lt;" and "&gt;" respectively.

is there any other means to achieve this.?

Comment: You could store the HTML in a string, and let Angular escape it for you. Lets say it's stored in a variable called `html`, you can do `{{ html }}`. and Angular will escape it

Comment: Is'n it just <pre></pre> ?